# how use dynamic action in tabular form in oracle apex?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I have Oracle APEX 4. I created a tabular form manually (with the `apex_item` package). It contains three fields.

- apex_application.g_f03: LOV (`select name display, product_id return from products`)
- apex_application.g_f04: text field "price"
- apex_application.g_f05: text field "quantity".

I would like to see the price of the product in f04 after choosing a product name (...f03). The SQL statement is like this:

```
select price from products where product_id = {..from f03}.
```

How to do it with dynamic action or javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I will give you a hint how to implement your scenario.

Things you need are to make it work:

- `custom tabular` for - you already have it
- `on demand process` that fetchs price of the product from db
- `dynamic action` to listen if value in `f03` changed

## on demand process

Create on demand process named `getPrice` with following code

```
declare
  v_price number;
begin
  select 
    price 
  into 
    v_price 
  from 
    products
  where 
    product_id = apex_application.g_x01;

  htp.p( v_price );

exception
  when others then
    htp.p(SQLERRM);
end;
```

## dynamic action

You have to listen event change on jQuery selector `:input[name=f03]`. Create dynamic action with true action `Execute JavaScript Code`.

Within true action you have to do ajax call to `on demand process`. The example code (working) is below:

```
var 
  xhr2,
  self = $(this.triggeringElement),
  productId = self.val(),
  row = self.closest('tr');

xhr = $.ajax({
  url:'wwv_flow.show',
  type:'post',
  dataType: 'text',
  traditional: true,
  data: {
    p_request: "APPLICATION_PROCESS=getPrice",
    p_flow_id: $v('pFlowId'),
    p_flow_step_id: $v('pFlowStepId'),
    p_instance: $v('pInstance'),
    //p_arg_names: [ item_id ],
    //p_arg_values: [ itemValue ],
    x01: productId
  },

  success: function( resultData, textStatus, ajaxObj ){ 
    //do stuff after fetching product price
    row.find( ':input[name=f04]' ).val( resultData )

  },

  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
    alert('Error occured while retrieving AJAX data: '+textStatus+"\n"+errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Put the stuff together and you will have answer to your question.

Ps.
Don't forget to mark answer as helpfull if it is answer to your question.